# Liferay7: Create custom URL for portlet

Tags: liferay-7

I need in LR7 to create a specific url, like this :

```
www.portal.com/news.php
```

I want this because I need to give a compatibility with older shared data (facebook).

`/news.php` will be a portletURL for my custom portlet.

Thanks in advance

Luis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do URL rewrites configuring **urlrewrite.xml** file, located in WEB-INF folder:

- https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

That file is used by UrlRewriteFilter inside Liferay, add a new rule with your URLs:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/news.php</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">%{context-path}/your_new_url</to>
</rule>
```

More info about UrlRewriteFilter syntaxis, see: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

If you are using Tomcat application server or you have an Apache Httpd web server, you can also add url rewrite rules at Tomcat o web server level, more information see:

- Rewrite at Tomcat level: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html
- Rewrite at Apache httpd web server: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html